# Checkbox Tags with Predefined Tags

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am developing a tag system in my Rails website. What I currently have is that a user can write tags seperated by spaces or commas. What I actually want to achieve is that a user can click the tags they want to include to their posts and the tags are not user generated, they must be predefined. How can I feed tags to database and present them as checkboxes to the user? I am sorry if the question is so needy, I am just looking for an advice to follow rather than the exact code I can implement. Thanks!

What I have (User can type tags and generate new ones):

[image: Current tags]

What I need (User can only select and associate, they cannot generate tags):

[image: Desired tags]

**review.rb**

```
class Review < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :reciever, class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sent_to_id"
    belongs_to :sender  , class_name: "User", foreign_key: "sent_from_id"
    has_many :taggings, dependent: :destroy
    has_many :tags, through: :taggings
    validates :content, presence: true, length: {maximum: 255}

    def self.tagged_with(name)
        Tag.find_by_name!(name).reviews
    end

    def all_tags=(names)
      self.tags = names.split(" ").map do |name|
          Tag.where(name: name.strip).first_or_create!
      end
    end

    def all_tags
      self.tags.map(&:name).join(", ")
    end
end
```

The tag code from form:

```
    <div class="field">
      <%= form.label :all_tags, 'What was the work about?' %>
      <%= form.text_field :all_tags, placeholder: "Tags separated with space" %>
    </div>
```

Comment: Way too broad ... Suggest you go research how to generate checkboxes from a given set of data in RoR, and how to apply custom styling to checkboxes/labels via CSS.

Comment: Can you give more information about what kind of tags do you need please?